# How to print output of external script to PyQt gui Window without extra "/n" characters

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to print the output of a called script to the window of a PyQt5 gui.  I have been able to successfully use subprocess to get the script to execute the called script, but it is printing the characters "/n" between each print statement in the called script.

**ex:  b'stuffz\nhere is another linet\ncool!\nhello worldt!\n\n\nWhat what?\nWhat what?\nWhat what?\nWhat what?\n'**

Can anyone help me figure out how to get my code to simply display the called script output (hellworld_final.py) in the exact format that it would display if I ran it directly?

Or, if anyone has a better method for calling an external script and displaying the output of the script as text in the PyQt gui, I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks in advance for you help!

Here is my current code:

helloworld_final.py

```
def cooz():
    print ('hello worldt!')

def tooz():
    print ("here is another linet")
    print ("cool!")

print ("stuffz")
tooz()
cooz()

print ()
print ()

print ("What what?")
print ("What what?")
```

pyqt_gui_test3.py

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication


class MyStream(QtCore.QObject):
    message = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyStream, self).__init__(parent)

    def write(self, message):
        self.message.emit(str(message))

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.pushButtonPrint = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButtonPrint.setText("Click Me!")

self.pushButtonPrint.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButtonPrint_clicked)

        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)

        self.layoutVertical = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.pushButtonPrint)
        self.layoutVertical.addWidget(self.textEdit)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButtonPrint_clicked(self):
        cmd = 'python /users/cmbp/p4e/helloworld_final.py'

        # execute script
        output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
        print (output)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_myStream_message(self, message):
        self.textEdit.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
        self.textEdit.insertPlainText(message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow()
    main.show()

    myStream = MyStream()
    myStream.message.connect(main.on_myStream_message)

    sys.stdout = myStream
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and change your print statement to this:

```
print(output.decode('utf-8'))
```

The output is of type 'bytes' and needs to be decoded to convert to a string for proper formatting.